# Detect common Password/PIN

Tags: php

I Made a PIN authentication on my website, and I don't want my user using common PINs like 12345, 11111, 121212, etc.

I tried this

```
    if($PIN=="111111" || $PIN="222222"){
   
    echo "This PIN is common";
}
```

But I think that Will be too long for a simple function?
How to simplify it?

Comment: regular expressions... you define a pattern to validate the PIN. However, it requires that YOU know what you want and what not.

Comment: You most likely do not want to handle authentication yourself. Have you tried looking for existing libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually quite simple, you want, for example, to avoid pins that have multiples iterations of a same character in a row OR/AND avoid pins that have a same character repeated more than X times in a string.

Using Regex we can easily achieve something like this: For example, the following will return 1 if 3 characters or more are in a row.

```
<?php
$pin = '111025'; 
if ( preg_match( '/(.)\1{2}/', $pin ) ) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

> **`RegEx`**.
> A regular expression is a sequence of characters that forms a search
> pattern. When you search for data in a text, you can use this search
> pattern to describe what you are searching for.

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `preg_match()` | Returns 1 if the pattern was found in the string and 0 if not |
| `( )` | You can use parentheses ( ) to apply quantifiers to entire patterns. They also can be used to select parts of the pattern to be used as a match |
| `.` | Find just one instance of any character |
| `n{x}` | Matches any string that contains a sequence of X n's |

*PHP `RegEx` @ https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp*